# Symbolizing Line using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

How to represent these lines so that the flow of direction is evident?

Due to the scale of the map, it looks like a solid.

[image: Line]

[image: Map]

Answer (score 2):

What about some sort of colour gradient?

In the picture below I used two Arrow line types with gradient fill.  One gradient started at blue and ended at transparent. The other started at transparent and ended at red. I set the arrow head length and thickness to zero and set the "Arrow width at start" the same as the "Arrow width" so it looks like a uniform stripe rather than an arrow.
[image]

You may have to play with the orientation of the gradient to get an acceptable result.  Look at the small line between the numbers 18 and 20, in the first image you can see the gradient orientation is vertical and lines that are more horizontal don't have as nice a gradient along their length as the more vertical lines.  In the second picture I used the expression `main_angle($geometry)` to get a different appearance, I also tried `degrees(azimuth( point_n(  $geometry ,1),point_n(  $geometry ,-1)))` (the bearing between the first and last vertices of the line - this might be a better choice, I don't know if main angle takes line direction into account)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion!

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of parallel lines and want to show only a part of them, depending on the map scale - when zooming out, some lines disappear, as on this animation:

[image]

Set a data defined override for stroke style and set it to `no` (not visible) or to `solid`, depending on the `$id` of the current feature. E.g. say to show only every 10th feauture: only if `$id` can be divided by 10 with no rest (using operator `%`), stroke-style is `solid` - otherwise `no`. The factor you use for dividing is based on the variable `@map_scale` (divided by a coefficient, here `100000` - tweak this value to fit your needs).

Use this expression:

```
if ($id % to_int( @map_scale /100000) =0,'solid', 'no')
```

*Result: black lines - the initial red lines are copied to another layer to show the effect of filterin out most of the lines (here at a scle of ca. 1:860'000):*
[image]

*Zooming out (here ca. 1:3'500'000), almost all of the black lines disappear - however, because of that, the flow of direction is still very clearly visible, whereas the red lines look like a solid fill:*

[image]

*Zooming in (here ca. 1:215'000), more of the black lines show up:*
[image]

**Edit**

My lines follow an order. If this is not the case, you can first create an additional attribute field that somehow creates a spatial order. You can use the start-point of the lines and get the x- or y-coordinate value and sort the lines accordingly. Use this value instead of `$id` in the expression above.

In the following example (see screenshot), I used the y-coordinate with this expression:

```
array_find (
    array_sort (
        array_agg( 
            y(start_point ($geometry))
        )
    ), 
    y(start_point ($geometry))
)
```

*Screenshot: red labels represent the order in whicht the lines were created (the `$id`). Black labels are dynamically created with the expression above:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion!

I notice that the creation of your lines followed an order. Is it possible to organize the geometry id to switch between even and odd?

My shapefile this organization is random

Comment: See edit at the bottom of the updated answer.

Comment: I really like this approach. I can see myself using it at some point.